# What is the right ZMQ architecture for a webserver sending fire-and-forget tasks to a bunch of webservers?

Tags: python, web-applications, distributed-computing, zeromq

I have a website which sends out heavy processing tasks to a worker server. Right now, there is only one worker server however in the future more will be added. These jobs are quite time-consuming (takes 5mins - 1 hour). The idea is to have a configuration where just building a new worker server should suffice to increase the capacity of the whole system, without needing extra configuration in the webserver parts.

Currently, I've done a basic implementation using python-zeromq, with the PUSH/PULL architecture.

Everytime there's a new job request, the webserver creates a socket, connects to one of the workers and sends the job (no reply needed, this is a fire-and-forget type of job):

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
socket.connect("tcp://IP:5000")
socket.send(msg)
```

And on the worker side this is running all the time:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
# bind to port in it's own IP
socket.bind("tcp://IP:5000")
print("Listening for messages...")
  while True:
  msg = socket.recv()
  <do something>
```

Now I looked more into this, and I think this is not quite the right way of doing it. Since adding a new worker server would require to add the IP of it to the webserver script, connect to both of them etc.

I would rather prefer the webserver to have a persistent socket on (and not create one everytime), and have workers connect to the webserver instead. Sort of like here:
https://github.com/taotetek/blog_examples/blob/master/python_multiprocessing_with_zeromq/workqueue_example.py

In short, as opposed to what is above, webserver's socket, binds to its own IP, and workers connects to it.I suppose then jobs are sent via round-robin style.

However what I'm worried about is, what happens if the webserver gets restarted (something that happens quite often) or gets offline for a while. Using zeromq, will all worker
connections will hang? Somehow become invalid? If the webserver goes down, will the current queue disappear?

In the current setup, things seem to run somewhat OK, but I'm not 100% sure what's the right (and not too complex) way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

From the [ZeroMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Why-We-Needed-MQ):

> Components can come and go dynamically and ØMQ will automatically reconnect.

If the underlying tcp connection is broken, ZeroMQ will repeatedly try to reconnect, sending your message once the connection succeeds.

Note that PAIR sockets are an exception. They don't automatically reconnect. (See the [zmq_socket docs](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-socket).)

Answer (score 0):

Binding on the server might work. Are you sure you won't ever need more than one web server, though? I'd consider putting a broker between your server(s) and workers.

Either way, I think persistent sockets are the way to go.